# delete specific array in array of objects with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying clean/filter a array to download in CSV, but I have a trouble to make this work...
I make this for to catch bigger array to make new array with old array.

oldArray:

```
[
  {
    Cpf: null,
    Nascimento: null,
    Sexo: null,
    OnlyPerson: false,
    IsFinanc: false,
    Senha: null,
    ConfirmaSenha: null,
    Remover: false,
    TipoStr: null,
    FiltroStr: null,
    IdAgenciaLogarComo: 0,
    DontHashPass: false,
    IsPessoaSimples: false,
    IsVisitante: false,
    Permited: false,
    Id: 21980,
    Nome: 'arrozfeijao',
    Ativo: true,
    Criacao: '2021-08-19T14:09:06.173',
    UltimaAlteracao: null,
    Email: 'arrozfeijao@gmail.com',
    IdAgencia: 1,
    IdEndereco: null,
    IdPermissao: 4,
    Observacoes: null,
    Endereco: {
      Cep: null,
      Logradouro: null,
      Numero: null,
      Complemento: null,
      Bairro: null,
      Estado: null,
      Cidade: null,
    },
    Parceiro: null,
    Contato: [],
    Permissao: {
      Id: 4,
      Descricao: 'Cliente',
      Pessoa: [],
    },
    AlterarSenha: [],
    Rede: [],
    Provider: [],
    AlertaPreco: [],
    Pedido2: [],
    _PageNumber: 0,
    PageNumber: 0,
    PageSize: 0,
    OrderBy: null,
    OrderDesc: false,
  },
];
```

Function to clean array:

```
for (const [key] of Object.entries(this.oldArray)) {
  let tempObject = {};
  for (const [keys, values] of Object.entries(this.oldArray[key])) {
    if (this.includesArray.includes(keys)) {
      tempObject[keys] = values;
    }
  }
  this.newArray[key] = tempObject;
}
```

works fine, I put in "includesArray" just I need to return

```
(ex. includesArray: ["Cpf", "Nascimento", "Sexo", "Id", "Nome", "Ativo", "Criacao", "UltimaAlteracao", "Email", "Observacoes", "Endereco"])
```

But -> "Endereco" is another array!
if I display
"newArray" it shows me that:

```
[
 {
  "Cpf": null,
  "Nascimento": null,
  "Sexo": null,
  "Id": 21980,
  "Nome": "arrozfeijao",
  "Ativo": true,
  "Criacao": "2021-08-19T14:09:06.173",
  "UltimaAlteracao": "2021-08-19T14:09:06.173",
  "Email": "arrozfeijao@gmail.com",
  "Observacoes": null,
  "Endereco": {
    "Id": 0,
    "Cep": null,
    "Logradouro": null,
    "Numero": null,
    "Complemento": null,
    "Bairro": null,
    "Estado": null,
    "Cidade": null
   }
  }
 ]
```

I need make this happen to this array:

```
  "Cpf": null,
  "Nascimento": null,
  "Sexo": null,
  "Id": 21980,
  "Nome": "arrozfeijao",
  "Ativo": true,
  "Criacao": "2021-08-19T14:09:06.173",
  "UltimaAlteracao": "2021-08-19T14:09:06.173",
  "Email": "arrozfeijao@gmail.com",
  "Observacoes": null,
  "Cep": null,
  "Logradouro": null,
  "Numero": null,
  "Complemento": null,
  "Bairro": null,
  "Estado": null,
  "Cidade": null
```

I need delete? i need pop()? I need Splice? and push again? I really don't know what to do...

Comment: It does not make sense to have two `Id` keys in the same object. Is that on purpose?

Comment: in fact, it wasn't supposed to exist  2 Id

Comment: So, can you update the post to show the correct output without two IDs?

Comment: Done! I removed the Id and posted the oldArray!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already declaring an `includes` array, you may as well define a constructor for your result object.

Here [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the properties from your `includedArray` from each passed object, further destructruing the `Endereco` property to isolate the unwanted `Id` and assigning the remaining properties to a parameter to later be [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into the final object.

```js
const input = [ { Cpf: null, Nascimento: null, Sexo: null, OnlyPerson: false, IsFinanc: false, Senha: null, ConfirmaSenha: null, Remover: false, TipoStr: null, FiltroStr: null, IdAgenciaLogarComo: 0, DontHashPass: false, IsPessoaSimples: false, IsVisitante: false, Permited: false, Id: 21980, Nome: 'arrozfeijao', Ativo: true, Criacao: '2021-08-19T14:09:06.173', UltimaAlteracao: null, Email: 'arrozfeijao@gmail.com', IdAgencia: 1, IdEndereco: null, IdPermissao: 4, Observacoes: null, Endereco: { Id: 0, Cep: null, Logradouro: null, Numero: null, Complemento: null, Bairro: null, Estado: null, Cidade: null, }, Parceiro: null, Contato: [], Permissao: { Id: 4, Descricao: 'Cliente', Pessoa: [], }, AlterarSenha: [], Rede: [], Provider: [], AlertaPreco: [], Pedido2: [], _PageNumber: 0, PageNumber: 0, PageSize: 0, OrderBy: null, OrderDesc: false, }, ];

const ResultObject = ({
  Cpf,
  Nascimento,
  Sexo,
  Id,
  Nome,
  Ativo,
  Criacao,
  UltimaAlteracao,
  Email,
  Observacoes,
  Endereco: { Id: _Id, ..._Endereco }, /* destructure the Id and '...rest' */
}) => ({
    Cpf,
    Nascimento,
    Sexo,
    Id,
    Nome,
    Ativo,
    Criacao,
    UltimaAlteracao,
    Email,
    Observacoes,
    ..._Endereco, /* spread the properties of the 'Endereco' object */
});

const result = input.map(ResultObject);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```